# Assembly load XML document from memorystream C#

Tags: c#, xml, .net-assembly

I have a database and I convert it to XML document like this:

```
            XmlDocument _XMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
           _XMLDoc.LoadXml(dataset.GetXml());
```

XML document is in memory and I need to read the assembly. So far I can only read the assembly if the file is saved to disk like this:

```
using (var stream= Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("_XMLDoc.xml"))
        {
                  ...
        }
```

How can I modify my code so I can read the assembly from memorystream?

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear. What do the XML file and assembly have anything to do with one another?  Why is there a dataset involved? Are you just trying to read the XML file that is an embedded resource in the assembly?

Comment: Ok, Why I have database is because my data is stored in a database. Why I need to have a xml file? is because I need it for a post processing and visualization. Now, my visualization code reads xml, and extracts some variables to construct and heatmap picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var _XMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
_XMLDoc.LoadXml(dataset.GetXml());
var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_XMLDoc.OuterXml);
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
{
    // ProcessStream(stream);
}
```